# Are there other biblical references where angels are disguised as humans?

Tags: biblical-basis, genesis, angels, sodom

I was reading **Genesis 19: Sodom and Gomorrah Destroyed** and in the [first verse](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+19:1&version=NIV), two angels are greeted by Lot as they arrive at the gates of Sodom. But instead of the "do not be afraid" speech that angels typically say, Lot offers to [wash their feet](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+19:2&version=NIV) and insists they spend the night at his house. What is going on here? I can't find a verse that specifically states the angels were disguised as men, but in [verse 5](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+19:6&version=NIV), the people of Sodom say, "Where are the **men** who came to you tonight? Bring them out to us so that we can have sex with them."

This would be really weird if the angels weren't disguised (actually it's weird either way) so I'm going to go ahead and say that they were disguised as men. Are there other biblical references where angels are disguised as humans?

Comment: The Bible doesn't really have a physical description of angels anywhere. Maybe they look the same as humans.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Samson's father Manoah did not recognize the Angel of the Lord until after he and the angel sacrificed to the Lord (Judges 13:16)

> The angel of the LORD replied, “Even though you detain me, I will not eat any of your food. But if you prepare a burnt offering, offer it to the LORD.” (Manoah did not realize that it was the angel of the LORD.)

Comment: Ah thanks. I think Judges 13:16 sums it up. `And the Angel of the LORD said to Manoah, “Though you detain Me, I will not eat your food. But if you offer a burnt offering, you must offer it to the LORD.” (For Manoah did not know He was the Angel of the LORD.)` Is verse 31 a typo?

Comment: Judges 13:31 is when the angel finally reveals himself and Manoah is shocked.

Comment: Judges Chapter 13 ends at verse 25. I don't see verse 31...

Comment: Err.. umm, its vs 31 in base 5.  Yeah... That's what I'm going with :)  Sorry - I don't know why I had that in my head.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @AffableGeek: Dec 25 = Oct 31... :P

Answer (score 13):

Apparently, some in New Testament times were familiar with some such incidents, and did not find it unlikely that it would happen, as related in the book of Hebrews:

> [Hebrews 13:2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%2013:2)
>
> Be not forgetful to entertain strangers: for thereby some have entertained angels unawares.

Comment: Jinx!  You owe me a soda!

Comment: Great, I thought of this verse. However, we're not sure it was Paul that wrote Hebrews.